# What is the C equivalent of List<List<Integer>> in Java?

Tags: java, c, list, type-conversion

I need to convert a small code from Java to C. In Java I was able to dynamically create a List of Lists of Integers without knowing the size of the outer list in advance. I might have the size of inner lists and each one is of different size. How can I do the same in C?

Comment: Thanks but this method require prior knowledge of the size (`dimension1_max`)

Comment: Yours can grow/shrink? It's unfortunate this isn't C++ :C

Comment: You can always resize using `realloc`

Comment: Or, you could implement a [`LinkedList`](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html) and have it work almost exactly like the Java version.

Comment: Thanks @Jon. Will the linked list be any slower than multidimensional arrays? Also, memory efficiency?

Comment: There is no pre-defined List in C.  You'd have to implement your own somehow, or struggle through just using C arrays.

Comment: @Kaur. Well, it's not the *most* efficient. But realistically, it won't make a difference unless your data set is somewhere in the millions.

Comment: @Jon The dataset is actually in millions :(

Comment: A linked Hash table (or more precisely Hash table of separate chaining with linked lists) would be great :) And It could act like your requirement

Comment: @Kaur even then, the difference is minimal, as long as your list implementation is efficient (there are thousands of sources online that are pretty well optimized). And I'd still wager that using linked lists is a better choice. It's a pretty standard way of dealing with dynamically-sized arrays.

Comment: Thanks @Jon. I will start with linked list.

Comment: @KcDoD: Thanks, I will look up linked hashtable in C.